# Sending an image in base64 via Telnet

Tags: c++, base64, telnet

I am currently working on a project for school and have ran into an issue with a large amount of data being sent via Telnet. If I send a message less than 10KB it is fine. However if I send a message that is above 10KB, I receive the following error "501 Syntax error - line too long" after a few minutes of it running.

Does anyone know of a better way to implement what I am trying to accomplish, that will preferably work with the send()? The data being sent is 5 pages (in Word) of an image in base64.

Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code portions that I am currently using, which work, with small amounts of data.

```
char *MailContents = new char[20000000];

std::ifstream in("C:\\test.txt");
std::string MailData((std::istreambuf_iterator<char(in)),std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()); 
//The following streams in the data into MailData() from a .txt file.


memcpy(MailContents, MailData.c_str(), MailData.length()); //This takes the data and copies it to MailContents
strcat(MailContents, "\r\n");

send(Connection, MailContents, strlen(MailContents), 0); //The following line will take the data in MailContents and echo it to the Telnet data section to be sent.

send(Connection, ".\r\n", strlen(".\r\n"), 0); //This line terminates the data entry and sends it.
```

Comment: Hmya, that's a fail whale.  Most any base64 decoder doesn't mind extra line feed and/or carriage return control codes in the string.  Telnet clients are more picky about it, they don't use a `char buffer[infinite]` when they call rcve().  Break it up.

Comment: If you are trying to implement an SMTP client, for instance, then it has line length limitations, and you MUST break up long lines accordingly: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#section-4.5.3

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thank you as well, by breaking it up, do you mean send it in sections (a section, a email)? By the way, I am sending this data via SMTP client.

Comment: @EAZYEASTON: I mean inserting line breaks at logical boundaries. SMTP has a 1000-character line length limit, but MIME has a 76-character line length limit, etc. And you have to be careful that you do not insert a line break in the middle of a word, an encoded byte, etc. Have a look at this blog article for some more info: http://mailformat.dan.info/body/linelength.html

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thank you this is exactly what I needed to know. Now, what would you recommend as far as streaming the .txt into a line then possibly inserting a line break (via loop, possibly?). Would you still use istreambuf_iterator, or do you know of a better way to implement this?